# Randomising results in array

Tags: c, arrays, random

I am trying to randomise an array and I have succesfully done it. But it is taking over 10 seconds to put out 16 (`PLAYERS`) numbers and it is using 99% cpu!!

Why is that?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PLAYERS 16

void getNames(char names[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN])
{
int x, y[PLAYERS] = {16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16},
    z, a = 1,
    b = 0;
char tempNames[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN];

while (a == 1)
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int random_number = rand() % PLAYERS;
    while (1)
    {
        if (y[b] == random_number)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            b++;
            strcpy(tempNames[b - 1], names[random_number]);
            y[b] = random_number;
            if (b == PLAYERS)
            {
                a = 0;
                
                /*Move temp array back to the original array*/
                for (z=0; z<PLAYERS; z++) {
                    strcpy(names[z], tempNames[z]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

## EDIT

I have just noticed that this code doesn't pick an original value for each random number!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger, or putting in printf's to see if it's doing what you expect?

Comment: Good ole `printf` debugging.

Comment: Where is `b` declared & initialized?

Comment: @Paul As I said it is outputting perfectly. But I immagine it is crunching far too many numbers!

Comment: Since you have working code, this would be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @BobMazanec Earlier on... Sorry

Comment: To what is `b` initialized?

Comment: Yes, we know it's doing too much. The printfs and/or debugger are for finding out what and why, not for testing the output. Move from "I imagine" to "I know why"!

Comment: Yeah, of you're going to post code like this, please include all the pertinent parts. Like the variable declarations.

Comment: @Andrew, under some definitions of the word "working"!

Comment: It would be helpful to put comments in your code to explain what you think it is doing. Then it's easier to explain what is not dooing what you think it is.

Comment: Where is `tempNames` declared, and `PLAYERS` and `NAME_LEN` defined?

Comment: Like Paul or Nit mentioned, printf debugging may help. Try to put a printf on the beginning of every loop (just below the while), and maybe one after the closing bracket of the loop, all telling where the program is, and maybe printing some relevant variables. With these you will likely see how those seconds are spent even with bare eyes (just remember to end with "\n" every printf string so they are flushed immediately).

Comment: You have an infinite loop with a random end condition, and you're copying strings around inside the loop. No wonder it takes forever. Fixing the error of having srand() inside the loop won't help. Throw away that hideous data structure and use one appropriate to the problem.

Comment: the call to srand() should be only performed once, so place that line of code before the first 'while' loop

Comment: this initialization:  y[PLAYERS] = {16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16} begs the question.  How do you know there will be 16 players.  Perhaps better to use y[PLAYERS] = {{16}} or initialize in a 'for' loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you keep seeding the random number generator; move the call to `srand` outside the loop.

This probably isn't slowing things much, but your inner loop shouldn't be a loop; either it breaks, or it sets the condition to cause a break the next iteration.

Here's something *much* simpler:

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
char tempname[NAME_LEN];
for ( a = PLAYERS-1; a>0; a-- ) {
    // Pick a position to swap with last name
    int r = rand() % (a+1);
    if ( r == a )
        continue;
    // Swap names[a] and names[r]
    strcpy( tempname, names[r] );
    strcpy( names[r], names[a] );
    strcpy( names[a], tempname );
}
```

Comment: This line is giving an error `strcpy( names[r], names[a] );` Thread 1 SIGABRT

Comment: the error message is indicating that one (or more) of the name[][] strings is not null terminated

Comment: @user3629249: Then you have something to fix; the above code isn't filling those strings, only swapping them around.

Answer (score 0):

You have incremented `b` and then used it *before* checking its range. So when `b == PLAYERS` you have already corrupted something else.

```
b++;
...
y[b] = random_number;
if (b == PLAYERS)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, things that bug me to no end that don't particularly pertain to your question.

- The system you have of having a forever loop with a break condition is bad mojo. That condition should be in the while loop condition.
- Why does that first loop exist? `while(a==1)`? is there a chance that incrementing `b` will never equal `PLAYERS`? It really really shouldn't. And that loop and flag can be axed.

You're getting a random number, quitting if the array at the NEXT index equals this random number, setting the array point to the number, and then doing stuff.

I believe you're exiting that inner forever loop due to luck.

Debug it, and break when `b == PLAYERS`. Look at what happens at the next iteration. Does it exit the loop when you want it to?